# Oracle Apex 5 - Checkbox list in where clause not working, why?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a quirky issue. I have a checkbox, a reports table and i'd like to click a checkbox or multi check boxes to return a result. In the Database I have a saved list of checkbox results seperated by a colon :

It all works except when I check box 'A' and 'C'. which is the first and last result in the database. I can click A and B or just A or just C or C and B but when i click A and C it doesn't work.

any clue?

```
select ...

from ...

where 

AND (CASE WHEN :P1_BENEFITS_TAG IS NOT NULL 
     THEN instr( ':'|| UPPER(b.BENEFITS_TAGS)||':',
                 ':'|| UPPER(:P1_BENEFITS_TAG) ||':' )
     ELSE 1 
     END) > 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your database row contains the string 'A:B:C:'.

When :P1_BENEFITS_TAG is any of the values 'A:B', 'B:C', 'A', 'B' or 'C' then the database row "contains" that value and your `INSTR` expression will return a number > 0.

However, 'A:B:C' does not contain the string 'A:C', so the INSTR will return 0 for that.

Comment: Great explanation of the logic, thank you. How would you suggest I get past that? I'm scratching my head

Comment: I think you'd probably need to convert the string in `P1_BENEFITS_TAG` to a table of values ('A', 'C') - see [regexp_substr example here](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement)

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for the link. I was able to solve it in a  messy sort of way by using regexp_subtr and instr @Tony Andrews